# Identify Excel Workbooks which connect to a given Excel file

Tags: excel, powerquery

My team has a large number of workbooks which connect via Power Query to a few static Excel files which are updated periodically with new data. I am trying to change these sources to a database to eliminate the need for these flat files, but my challenge is in ensuring all workbooks which connect to the static files are updated.

I am wondering if there is a way to do some sort of reverse lookup of query connections to a particular workbook so I can see which workbooks reference a given data file. I have googled a variety of questions but haven't had any luck finding an answer yet. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for some kind of trace dependents function that works across workbooks. I think the only way to do it would be essentially brute force, looking in all the workbooks and finding out what they connect to.

Comment: This cannot be done